# Send Token ID to server side Android

Tags: android, firebase, server, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send notifications without using Firebase console (I want to make with server side). For this,I am trying to send device token id to web service. I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging in this Android project. How can I do this?

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService{

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Token: " + token);

        sendRegistrationToServer(token);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // send token to web service ??

    }
```

Thank you !

Comment: do you want to store your token ID on firebase server or your own?

Comment: @AmeerHamza i wanna store on firebase server

Comment: Is the below answers are helping? Or Still, You have a problem to store into firebase server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) creat firebase ref like this one

```
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
            // send token to web service ??   
        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("server/saving-data/IDs");
        // then store your token ID
        ref.push().setvalue(token)
    }
```

For more read [this post](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data)

Answer (score 4):

First you should have some server running to receive your token and store. Then you can make an API call from your App to post FCM token to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code given below in your class and this method will be exected from "onTokenRefresh()" method automatically. Just make sure you replace the web-service url with your own server's web-service url.

```
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String deviceToken) {

class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String deviceToken = params[0];



        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
            "http://lib-dm.process9.com/libertydm/ValidateUserHandler.ashx");// replace with your url
        httpPost.addHeader("Content-type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        BasicNameValuePair usernameBasicNameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair(
            "UserId", paramUsername);  // Make your own key value pair
        BasicNameValuePair passwordBasicNameValuePAir = new BasicNameValuePair(
            "Password", paramPassword);// make your own key value pair

        // You can add more parameters like above

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairList.add(usernameBasicNameValuePair);
        nameValuePairList.add(passwordBasicNameValuePair);

        try {
            UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                nameValuePairList);
            httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);

            try {
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient
                    .execute(httpPost);
                InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity()
                    .getContent();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    inputStreamReader);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String bufferedStrChunk = null;
                while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                }

                return stringBuilder.toString();

                } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                    System.out
                        .println("First Exception coz of HttpResponese :"
                            + cpe);
                    cpe.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    System.out
                        .println("Second Exception coz of HttpResponse :"
                            + ioe);
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            System.out
                .println("An Exception given because of UrlEncodedFormEntity argument :"
                    + uee);
            uee.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}

SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(token);
}
```